# Merge semi-duplicated rows in R

Tags: r, merge, duplicates, rows

I have a data frame (called A in example below) that looks like this subset:

```
Survey HaulNo Year Species Unsexed Males Females HaulUnique Lat_long  
FRGF      1   2000  134567      NA     4      NA     1_2000     50.7_-2.5 
FRGF      1   2000  134567      NA    NA       5     1_2000     50.7_-2.5 
FRGF      2   2003  134578      10    NA      NA     2_2003     49.5_-1.5 
FRGF      3   1998  123557      NA    NA       7     3_1998     50.1_-0.5
FRGF      3   1998  123557      NA     3      NA     3_1998     50.1_-0.5
```

I would like to merge these rows so that they look like the data below:

```
Survey HaulNo Year Species Unsexed Males Females HaulUnique Lat_long  
FRGF      1   2000  134567      NA     4      5     1_2000     50.7_-2.5 
FRGF      2   2003  134578      10    NA      NA    2_2003     49.5_-1.5 
FRGF      3   1998  123557      NA     3      7     3_1998     50.1_-0.5
```

Essentially, I want to merge rows so that the information lying within the columns "Unsexed", "Males" and "Females" is all within one row, rather than in the current situation where this data is split and duplicate information occurs on multiple rows regarding same species and haul etc. It is essential that when I merge the rows everything else is maintained and kept unique, as each row (once merged) represents a unique haul.

I don't want to apply any sort of sum/mean/other function to these 3 columns and I want keep all my other variables the same. I also do not want to create any additional new columns and would like to keep the NAs if possible.

NB. Given I have a huge dataset, I am not always aware a) which rows are semi-duplicated and b) which combination of Unsexed/Males/Females each row has information on.

I have tried a variety of ways to do this none of which I've got to work, partly because as a beginner in R I have struggled to really understand the functions I've tried and apply them to my data (aggregate, ddply, cast).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or using `data.table`, you could do something like `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sort(x)[1L]), by = .(Survey, HaulNo, Year, Species, HaulUnique, Lat_long)]`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for this code. It runs fine but it doesn't actually merge the rows? It just rearranges the Unsexed, Males, Females columns to the right side of my data frame...

Comment: @KatherineMaltby I think there's a problem with your process. Both solutions work, but the second one replaces `NA`s with zeros, as it uses a `sum` function with `na.rm=T`.

Comment: Your `dput` is different from above. Look at `HaulUnique` column. You have 2 different values for `HaulNo` = 1. The solutions provided here assume that your unique row identifier is based on the columns `Survey, HaulNo, Year, Species, HaulUnique, Lat_long`, so you can merge them. Otherwise it's impossible.

Comment: Sorry that was complete human error in transferring data into the question edit. Those codes do work now. Thank you so much! I will remove the edit as it is confusing and original solutions worked. Sincere apologies.

Comment: No worries. Here my assumption is that every time you want to merge some rows you will have ONLY 1 value and then `NA`(s), right? Is it possible to have more values? So, for example is it possible to want to merge 3 rows that have `4,NA,3` in column `Males`? If yes, how do you want the merge to treat the values `4` and `3`?

Comment: Good question, that would have previously been a predicament for me, but I have restructured the data in a way so that there is only 1 value for each.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
aggregate(
  df[, c("Unsexed", "Males", "Females")],
  df[, c("Survey", "HaulNo", "Year", "Species", "HaulUnique", "Lat_long")],
  FUN = sum,
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I get an error when I run this: Error in `[.data.frame`(A, , c("Survey", "HaulNo", "Year", "Species",  : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: make sure that you use the correct name of the data.frame. I assumed `df`. Furthermore make sure that the names in the aggregate statement match with the column names of your data.frame. Matching means identical!

Comment: Fixed the error, code runs but doesn't solve the problem, just adds the unsexed, males, females columns to the right of the dataframe.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example. Give us the output of `dput(df)`. Show the output of my code and what if should be.

Comment: Sorry, I've not done a question on Stackoverflow before, where is best to put the output?

Comment: @KatherineMaltby you can just put it under your question, or on top where you say how your dataset looks like.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works perfectly - human error was confusing me earlier.